# Limiting # of Lines in a Log/Buffer File

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I've got a small program running on an OpenWRT router that logs to a remote MySQL database. In the event that the database becomes unavailable the program writes to a buffer file (/var/buffer) to protect against data loss. Thing is, since it's being stored on the router itself, there's a chance of running out of room fairly quickly if the database is down for too long.

I figure that if I keep the file to a max of 20,000 lines, discarding the oldest ones as new ones are written (once the max size has been reached), I can minimize my data losses and not have to worry about running out of storage space (a bit of loss isn't the end of the world, and I'd rather keep the newest stuff than the oldest).

From my research I understand that the first line of a file cannot be removed without rewriting the entire file (no good, too time-consuming), and every time I think I'm close to another solution it falls apart.

Is there a better way? Or is re-writing the 20k-line file every time I have a new line to add my only option?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `log_LastLineNo` variable which will store line number of last line written in log at that instant (For the first time, at the very start it will be `0`).

Keep writing to file until you write 20,000 lines, and keep updating `log_LastLineNo`.
After that start overwriting the file from start, and set a variable `log_full = 1`.

Now
**Case 1:** `log_full = 0` & `log_LastLineNo = [some value < 20000]`
In this case read from start till `log_LastLineNo`

**Case 2:** `log_full = 1` & `log_LastLineNo = [some value < 20000]`
In this case start reading from `log_LastLineNo + 1` till line 20000 and again from start to `log_LastLineNo`.

Comment: This is one of the approaches that I considered. Unfortunately, there is the chance of my program stopping and restarting, so the `log_LastLineNo` would be lost. I suppose I could save that to a separate file...